# How to detect which driver is used for touch device?

Tags: device-firmware, external-display

I've connected an IR touch frame to my android device and it works great, however the touch input is rotated by 90 degrees.
I would like to find out which driver is used by the touch device, but I have no clue about how to do that.
Is there any command I could use to check that?

`lsusb` does not point to any drivers unfortunately.

Thank you